# how to make bouncing ball application

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have been following http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1798 tutorial to make bouncing ball app.
But what i want to do is make 20-30 balls which can be dragged anywhere in the iphone screen on user touch and also can be dropped anywhere in the screen.So please can anyone suggest me on this -- how to do this in i phone not using cocos2d please help me out or give me some links or useful information any help will be appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

As you are working in mentioned code, you can write `touchesMoved` method where you will handle the position of `ballView`.

```
- (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *anyTouch = [touches anyObject];
   [self setCenter:[anyTouch locationInView:[self superView]];
}
```

try this.

or this updated one

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    if ([touches count] == 1) {
        UITouch *newTouch = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]]; 
        UITouch *lastTouch = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView: [self superview]];
        NSLog(@"xxxxxggdfgdfgfdgdfg%f",newTouch.x);
        NSLog(@"yyyyyyggdfgdfgfdgdfg%f",newTouch.y);
        xDif = newTouch.x - lastTouch.x; 
        yDif = newTouch.y - lastTouch.y;


        }
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xDif, yDif);
        [self setTransform: CGAffineTransformConcat([self transform], translate)]; 
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help ravin but code that u suggested is not working it drags my whole view not ball.What i want to do is after making balls using drawrect method each and every ball should be dragged and dropped on user touch independently.

Comment: write this method in BallView class.... that inherits UIImageView.(not in any other view)...this will only shift your balls position.

Comment: also, do not forget to write [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES] in BallView's init method.

Comment: hey ravin i tried both of yours methos but didnt work.If i will put above tranform one method then that will not allow touchesmoved method of root viewcontroller to call so I wont be able to dragand drop any of the balls so but though thanks budy

Comment: where are putting this methods? in which class?

Comment: have you seen that tutorial which I have been following? I have a rootviewController which have touchesvegan,moved and ended method and the method you suggested me i have put that code in ballview class and though its not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timer {

pos = CGPointMake(7.0, 14.0);
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

and call the method using selector

-(void)onTimer{
    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x+pos.x ,image.center.y+pos.y );
    if (image.center.x>320 || image.center.x<0) 
        pos.x=-pos.x;

```
    if (image.center.y>460 || image.center <0 ) 
    pos.y=-pos.y;
```

}

by this u can move image in iphone screen and use touch move to hold that image

Comment: hey thanks vijay but i have already done that using NSTimer and my app is also working but I want it for 20-30 balls.User should be able to touch every of ball and user should also be able to drag each and evry of 30 balls and also drop that of 30 balls so any help for that?